# Execute Powershell script from Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell

I've been looking around the web and on Stackoverflow but hadn't found an answer to this question. How would you execute a Powershell script from Node.js? The script is on the same server as the Node.js instance.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can just spawn a child process "powershell.exe" and listen to stdout for command output and stderr for errors:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
child = spawn("powershell.exe",["c:\\temp\\helloworld.ps1"]);
child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});
child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});
child.on("exit",function(){
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});
child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for the help. This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: I know this is old but can the powershell be run with admin permissions?

Comment: @Vandervidi have a look at the [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) npm package. It provides a function `elevate` which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there are any way to pass a relative path to powershell script as second parameter?

Comment: How to pass arguments for the script file from nodejs

Comment: This is great in principle, but won't work with scripts with paths that have embedded spaces; it's generally better to invoke scripts via the `-File` parameter (and with the `-NoProfile` parameter for predictability), which also makes it easier to pass arguments: `child = spawn("powershell.exe", [ '-noprofile', '-file', "c:\\temp\\helloworld.ps1", "arg1", "arg2"])`. Without `-File`, `-Command` is implied (in Windows PowerShell, not in PowerShell Core). /cc @Ramyachinna

Comment: hi @muffel can we use nodejs child process to run dotnet commands??

Comment: How it works in Linux: spawn("powershell.EXE" ? because it should be portable. Or we need to have different versions for Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 54):

The newer way to do this

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('command here', {'shell':'powershell.exe'}, (error, stdout, stderr)=> {
    // do whatever with stdout
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved with this solution!

Comment: How can you get this to work with an external powershell script?

Comment: Read the script in as a string and replace 'command here' with the variable

Comment: I looked up for child_process in npm repo and what I found in this link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/child_process 

has this message under Read Me section:
** Security holding package - This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. **

Also it has just 1 version and 7 years old. 

Just wanted to make sure I got the right one

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner child_process is a built in package. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 10):

This option works for me, when the script is not already there, but you want to generate some commands dynamically, send them, and work with the results back on node.

```js
var PSRunner = {
    send: function(commands) {
        var self = this;
        var results = [];
        var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
        var child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["-Command", "-"]);

        child.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
            self.out.push(data.toString());
        });
        child.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
            self.err.push(data.toString());
        });

        commands.forEach(function(cmd){
            self.out = [];
            self.err = [];
            child.stdin.write(cmd+ '\n');
            results.push({command: cmd, output: self.out, errors: self.err});
        });
        child.stdin.end();
        return results;
    },
};

module.exports = PSRunner;
```

Comment: Will this not add all errors and output to the last executed command? I've asked some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778574/how-is-this-used-in-a-function-and-is-it-required?noredirect=1#comment118046903_66778574).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
let child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["c:/temp/helloworld.ps1"], { shell: true });
child.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Powershell Data: ", data);
});
child.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Powershell Errors: ", data);
});
child.on("exit", function() {
  console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});
child.stdin.end();
```

**NOTE:** In Windows, Powershell script can be added irrespective of the full path based on path which you are running this from.