# Get PowerShell return value using JScript

Tags: powershell, jscript

Below is a PowerShell function:

```
function ReturnSomething {
    return 42 
}
```

How can I get this PowerShell return value (`42`) by using JScript?

Comment: Some context would be useful here. Why do you need to access this from JScript? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js.

Comment: Is this maybe what you're looking for..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js

Comment: @AlexanderObersht : This may looks like duplicate but require() and spawn() are not part of standard JavaScript. require() and spawn() are Node.js functions. What i want is just using standard JavaScript function to get the return value from powershell.