# Need alternative to ActiveXObject Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, activexobject

I am using node webkit to build some automation tools, and I'm trying to set up an e-mail notice upon a particular event firing. What I need to do is send an e-mail from my outlook account to a client, however, being that node webkit uses chromium, I'm having some issues using the ActiveXObject to create an Outlook object in Javascript. I have tried win32ole, but I cannot install it for some reason, and I'm finding very little by way of an alternative.

If anyone has ideas of how I can access outlook using node webkit, or some other javascript library to work around this limitation, I'm all ears.

Comment: Do you really need to actually automate Outlook or can you just send an email via SMTP (in which case there are many such modules on npm for doing that)?

Comment: I need to send an e-mail from my outlook account, and I don't have admin to our smtp servers.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181488/111794) answer about using Powershell from Node.js. You could automate Outlook from Powershell, or you could write a script in Javascript that would run under `CScript.exe` to do the same.