# How to invoke Powershell script in a different folder using Gulp

Tags: node.js, powershell, gulp

I was able to implement [Splitting gulpfile into multiple file](https://gist.github.com/heldr/a3429c31ff45937c13de) without any issues. Now, my task (below) is moved from `./gulpfile.js` to `./tasks/database-publish.js`. In this task, I'm using `var exec = require('child_process').exec` to run a Powershell (PS1) I wrote that lives in `../DbDeploy.ps1` relative to the new gulp-task file.

In this task, I'm executing my ps1 [file via gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271683/1932324)

```js
gulp.task("zzz_Run-DB-Deply",
        function(callback) {
            console.log('running db deploy');
            plugins.exec('Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  ..\DbDeploy.ps1',
                function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log(stdout);
                    callback(err);
                });
        });
```

If I run `Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  ..\DbDeploy.ps1` in Powershell from the `task` directory, it works fine. However, when I run the `zzz_Run-DB-Deploy` task, I keep getting an exception:

> Process terminated with code 0

My suspicion is with `..\DbDeploy.ps1`. I think `\D` is being used as escape character. But I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Javascript requires that you escape the backslash in strings.

Comment: Like this? `Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  ..\\DbDeploy.ps1`

Comment: Yes, exactly! Does it work?

Comment: It did, but I realized that wasn't my issue. Posted the answer below.

Comment: Using an unescaped backslash in a string literal is still wrong. You should fix that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. The issue was with transfer of the `plugins` from the `gulpfile.js` to `tasks/gulp-task.js`

In order to give everyone some context, it'd be best to paste the tasks here. I though that I could send in all of the referenced plugins to my `tasks` folder using a `plugins` variable. Unfortunately, I was wrong.

```js
module.exports = function (gulp, config, plugins) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('Starting the database migration.');
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    gulp.task("zzz_Run-DB-Deply",
        function(callback) {
            console.log('running db deploy');
            exec("Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  ..\DbDeploy.ps1",
                function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log(stderr);
                    console.log(stdout);
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err);
                });
        });
    gulp.task("Build-DB-Project",
        function (callback) {
            console.log('running build DB project');
            var targets = ["Build"];
            if (config.runCleanBuilds) {
                targets = ["Clean", "Build"];
            }
            return gulp.src("./Project/*.csproj")
                .pipe(plugins.foreach(function (stream, file) {
                    return stream
                        .pipe(plugins.debug({ title: "Building" }))
                        .pipe(plugins.msbuild({
                            targets: targets,
                            configuration: config.buildConfiguration,
                            logCommand: false,
                            verbosity: "minimal",
                            stdout: true,
                            errorOnFail: true,
                            maxcpucount: config.maxCpuCount,
                            toolsVersion: config.toolsVersion
                        }));
                }));
        });

}
```

In order to fix this issue, I added a new `exe` variable referencing `var exec = require('child_process').exec;` At which point, running `exec("Powershell.exe pwd")` showed me that my working directory was in fact the root of my project where `gulpfile.js` and `DbDeploy.ps1` both live. Thus, I knew to change the file path from `../DbDeploy.ps1` to `DbDeploy.ps`.

```js
exec("Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  DbDeploy.ps1",
                function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log(stderr);
                    console.log(stdout);
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err);
                });
```