# Passing Powershell Objects to Node.JS / Electron and wrap them in HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, object, electron

I'm trying to write a little tool in Electron that calls Powershell scripts.

I know how to get Powershell output into my Script from this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181488/3161671

So I have

```
<script>
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
    child = spawn("powershell.exe",["C:\\PowershellScript\\get-process.ps1"]);
    child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
        console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
    });
    child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
        console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    });
    child.on("exit",function(){
        console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    });
    child.stdin.end(); //end input
</script>
```

However, I don't quite understand how to call object members from my PS output (`child.stdout.ProcessName` for example.)

I want to be able to loop through the output and format some members in a table (if this is reasonable):

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>CPU(s)</th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>ProcessName</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0,35</td>
    <td>1824</td>
    <td>conhost</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.725</td>
    <td>3115</td>
    <td>firefox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What's the cleanest way to achieve this? I've seen people embedding HTML tags in their Powershell scripts, but I think it makes more sense to use JavaScript for the Object-to-HTML and formatting, doesn't it?

Comment: `stdout` isn't going to be the object it's going to be a formatted version of the object.  Converting to JSON may give you a more usable format for JavaScript (I assume you can parse it).  You do that like this   `Get-Process -Name WmiPrvSE | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2`.  So that you only get JSON, you need to add the following switch when you call `powershell.exe`, `-NoLogo`.  Try to keep the Depth as shallow as possible.  The process object has many rich properties.  If you are serializing many of them with event depth 2, it will take some time.

Comment: Sounds good, that answers one part of the question. And how do I parse it in Javascript to get objects and format them in HTML? I tried `JSON.parse(child)` but that gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, *standard Output* is not going to work in this case because that will have its own formatted way to display. I have few conversion functions apart from the native powershell conversion. You should try them and then you should parse the output.

Here you go:

- **Convertto-JsonIfAblePSObject**

Usage has been mentioned in the comment sections for easy understanding.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new PSObject where all properties of the original object that are not able to be
    properly serialized to JSON are converted to a value which can be properly converted to JSON.

    This includes the following types:
    *   DateTime

    This conducts a deep property search
.Example 
    Convert an custom PSObject to have parsable dates in Json

    $customObject = New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{ Date = Get-Date; Number = 23; InnerDate = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Date=Get-Date;} }

    ## BAD Json
    PS C:\dev> $customObject | ConvertTo-Json
    {
        "Date":  {
                     "value":  "\/Date(1410372629047)\/",
                     "DisplayHint":  2,
                     "DateTime":  "Wednesday, September 10, 2014 2:10:29 PM"
                 },
        "Number":  23,
        "InnerDate":  {
                          "Date":  {
                                       "value":  "\/Date(1410372629047)\/",
                                       "DisplayHint":  2,
                                       "DateTime":  "Wednesday, September 10, 2014 2:10:29 PM"
                                   }
                      }
    }

    ## Good Json
    PS C:\dev> $customObject | ConvertTo-JsonifiablePSObject | ConvertTo-Json
    {
        "Date":  "2014-09-10T14:10:29.0477785-04:00",
        "Number":  23,
        "InnerDate":  {
                          "Date":  "2014-09-10T14:10:29.0477785-04:00"
                      }
    }

#>
function ConvertTo-JsonifiablePSObject
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [PSObject]$Object
    )

    $newObjectProperties = @{}

    foreach ($property in $Object.psobject.properties)
    {
        $value = $property.Value

        if ($property.TypeNameOfValue -eq "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject")
        {
            $value = ConvertTo-JsonifiablePSObject -Object $property.Value
        }
        elseif ($property.TypeNameOfValue -eq "System.DateTime")
        {
            $value = $property.Value.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK")
        }

        $newObjectProperties[$property.Name] = $value
    }

    return New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $newObjectProperties
}

$json=$kbm | ConvertTo-Json
```

- **Convertto-PSON**

  ```
  function ConvertTo-PSON

  {
  <#
   .SYNOPSIS
     creates a powershell object-notation script that generates the same object data
   .DESCRIPTION
     This produces 'PSON', the powerShell-equivalent of JSON from any object you pass to it. It isn't suitable for the huge objects produced by some of the cmdlets such as Get-Process, but fine for simple objects
   .EXAMPLE
     $array=@()
     $array+=Get-Process wi* |  Select-Object Handles,NPM,PM,WS,VM,CPU,Id,ProcessName 
     ConvertTo-PSON $array

   .PARAMETER Object 
     the object that you want scripted out
   .PARAMETER Depth
     The depth that you want your object scripted to
   .PARAMETER Nesting Level
     internal use only. required for formatting
  #>

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
      [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][AllowNull()] $inputObject,
      [parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $depth = 16,
      [parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $NestingLevel = 1,
      [parameter(Position = 3, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $XMLAsInnerXML = 0
  )

  BEGIN { }
  PROCESS
  {
      If ($inputObject -eq $Null) { $p += '$Null'; return $p } # if it is null return null
      $padding = [string]'  ' * $NestingLevel # lets just create our left-padding for the block
      $ArrayEnd=0; #until proven false
      try
      {
          $Type = $inputObject.GetType().Name # we start by getting the object's type
          if ($Type -ieq 'Object[]') { $Type = "$($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name)" } # see what it really is
          if ($depth -ilt $NestingLevel) { $Type = 'OutOfDepth' } #report the leaves in terms of object type
          elseif ($Type -ieq 'XmlDocument' -or $Type -ieq 'XmlElement')
          {
              if ($XMLAsInnerXML -ne 0) { $Type = 'InnerXML' }
              else
              { $Type = 'XML' }
          } # convert to PS Alias
              # prevent these values being identified as an object
          if (@('boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'datetime', 'decimal', 'double', 'float', 'single', 'guid', 'int', 'int32',
          'int16', 'long', 'int64', 'OutOfDepth', 'RuntimeType', 'PSNoteProperty', 'regex', 'sbyte', 'string',
          'timespan', 'uint16', 'uint32', 'uint64', 'uri', 'version', 'void', 'xml', 'datatable', 'List`1',
          'SqlDataReader', 'datarow', 'ScriptBlock', 'type') -notcontains $type)
          {
              if ($Type -ieq 'OrderedDictionary') { $Type = 'HashTable' }
              elseif ($Type -ieq 'PSCustomObject') { $Type = 'PSObject' } #
              elseif ($inputObject -is "Array") { $Type = 'Array' } # whatever it thinks it is called
              elseif ($inputObject -is "HashTable") { $Type = 'HashTable' } # for our purposes it is a hashtable
              elseif (($inputObject | gm -membertype Properties | Select name | Where name -like 'Keys') -ne $null) { $Type = 'generic' } #use dot notation
              elseif (($inputObject | gm -membertype Properties | Select name).count -gt 1) { $Type = 'Object' }
          }
          write-verbose "$($padding)Type:='$Type', Object type:=$($inputObject.GetType().Name), BaseName:=$($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name) $NestingLevel "
          switch ($Type)
          {
              'ScriptBlock'{ "[$type] {$($inputObject.ToString())}" }
              'InnerXML'        { "[$type]@'`r`n" + ($inputObject.OuterXMl) + "`r`n'@`r`n" } # just use a 'here' string
              'DateTime'   { "[datetime]'$($inputObject.ToString('s'))'" } # s=SortableDateTimePattern (based on ISO 8601) local time
              'Boolean'    {
                  "[bool] $(&{
                      if ($inputObject -eq $true) { "`$True" }
                      Else { "`$False" }
                  })"
              }
              'string'     {
                  if ($inputObject -match '[\r\n]') { "@'`r`n$inputObject`r`n'@" }
                  else { "'$($inputObject -replace '''', '''''')'" }
              }
              'Char'       { [int]$inputObject }
              { @('byte', 'decimal', 'double', 'float', 'single', 'int', 'int32', 'int16', 'long', 'int64', 'sbyte', 'uint16', 'uint32', 'uint64') -contains $_ }
              { "$inputObject" } # rendered as is without single quotes
              'PSNoteProperty' { "$(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.Value -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel))" }
              'Array'      { "`r`n$padding@(" + ("$($inputObject | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; ",$(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd)) + "`r`n$padding)" }
              'HashTable'  { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject.GetEnumerator() | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; "; '$($_.Name)' = " + (ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $_.Value -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1)) })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding}") }
              'PSObject'   { "`r`n$padding[pscustomobject]@{" + ("$($inputObject.PSObject.Properties | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; "; '$($_.Name)' = " + (ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1)) })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding}") }
              'Dictionary' { "`r`n$padding@{" + ($inputObject.item | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; '; ' + "'$_'" + " = " + (ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.Value[$_] -depth $depth -NestingLevel $NestingLevel+1) }) + '}' }
              'Generic'    { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject.Keys | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; ";  $_ =  $(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.$_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding}") }
              'Object'     { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | Select-Object name | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; ";  $($_.name) =  $(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $NestingLevel -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding}") }
              'XML'        { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | where name -ne 'schema' | Select-Object name | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; ";  $($_.name) =  $(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding}") }
              'Datatable'  { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject.TableName)=`r`n$padding @(" + "$($inputObject | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; ",$(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "`r`n$padding  )`r`n$padding}") }
              'DataRow'    { "`r`n$padding@{" + ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | Select-Object name | ForEach {$ArrayEnd=1; "; $($_.name)=  $(ConvertTo-PSON -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })".Substring($ArrayEnd) + "}") }
              default { "'$inputObject'" }
          }
      }
      catch
      {
          write-error "Error'$($_)' in script $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName) $($_.InvocationInfo.Line.Trim()) (line $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)) char $($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine) executing $($_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand) on $type object '$($inputObject.Name)' Class: $($inputObject.GetType().Name) BaseClass: $($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name) "
      }
      finally { }
  }
  END { }
  }
  ```
- **Convertto-YAML**

  ```
  function ConvertTo-YAML
      {
  <#
   .SYNOPSIS
   creates a YAML description of the data in the object
   .DESCRIPTION
   This produces YAML from any object you pass to it. It isn't suitable for the huge objects produced by some of the cmdlets such as Get-Process, but fine for simple objects
   .EXAMPLE
     $array=@()
   $array+=Get-Process wi* |  Select-Object Handles,NPM,PM,WS,VM,CPU,Id,ProcessName 
   ConvertTo-YAML $array

   .PARAMETER Object 
   the object that you want scripted out
   .PARAMETER Depth
   The depth that you want your object scripted to
   .PARAMETER Nesting Level
   internal use only. required for formatting
  #>

     [CmdletBinding()]
     param (
          [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][AllowNull()] $inputObject,
          [parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $depth = 16,
          [parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $NestingLevel = 0,
          [parameter(Position = 3, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $false)] [int] $XMLAsInnerXML = 0
     )

     BEGIN { }
     PROCESS
     {
          If ($inputObject -eq $Null) { $p += 'null'; return $p } # if it is null return null
          if ($NestingLevel -eq 0) { '---' }

          $padding = [string]'  ' * $NestingLevel # lets just create our left-padding for the block
          try
          {
            $Type = $inputObject.GetType().Name # we start by getting the object's type
            if ($Type -ieq 'Object[]') { $Type = "$($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name)" } #what it really is
            if ($depth -ilt $NestingLevel) { $Type = 'OutOfDepth' } #report the leaves in terms of object type
            elseif ($Type -ieq 'XmlDocument' -or $Type -ieq 'XmlElement')
            {
               if ($XMLAsInnerXML -ne 0) { $Type = 'InnerXML' }
               else
               { $Type = 'XML' }
            } # convert to PS Alias
            # prevent these values being identified as an object
            if (@('boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'datetime', 'decimal', 'double', 'float', 'single', 'guid', 'int', 'int32',
            'int16', 'long', 'int64', 'OutOfDepth', 'RuntimeType', 'PSNoteProperty', 'regex', 'sbyte', 'string',
            'timespan', 'uint16', 'uint32', 'uint64', 'uri', 'version', 'void', 'xml', 'datatable', 'List`1',
            'SqlDataReader', 'datarow', 'ScriptBlock', 'type') -notcontains $type)
            {
               if ($Type -ieq 'OrderedDictionary') { $Type = 'HashTable' }
               elseif ($Type -ieq 'PSCustomObject') { $Type = 'PSObject' } #
               elseif ($inputObject -is "Array") { $Type = 'Array' } # whatever it thinks it is called
               elseif ($inputObject -is "HashTable") { $Type = 'HashTable' } # for our purposes it is a hashtable
               elseif (($inputObject | gm -membertype Properties |
               Select name | Where name -like 'Keys') -ne $null) { $Type = 'generic' } #use dot notation
               elseif (($inputObject | gm -membertype Properties | Select name).count -gt 1) { $Type = 'Object' }
            }
            write-verbose "$($padding)Type:='$Type', Object type:=$($inputObject.GetType().Name), BaseName:=$($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name) "

            switch ($Type)
            {
               'ScriptBlock'{ "{$($inputObject.ToString())}" }
               'InnerXML'     { "|`r`n" + ($inputObject.OuterXMl.Split("`r`n") | foreach{ "$padding$_`r`n" }) }
               'DateTime' { $inputObject.ToString('s') } # s=SortableDateTimePattern (based on ISO 8601) using local time
               'Boolean' {
                    "$(&{
                       if  ($inputObject -eq $true) { '`true' }
                       Else  { '`false' }
                     })"
               }
               'string' {
                    $String = "$inputObject"
                    if ($string -match '[\r\n]' -or $string.Length -gt 80)
                    {
                      # right, we have to format it to YAML spec.
                      ">`r`n" # signal that we are going to use the readable 'newlines-folded' format
                      $string.Split("`n") | foreach {
                           $bits = @(); $length = $_.Length; $IndexIntoString = 0; $wrap = 80
                           while ($length -gt $IndexIntoString + $Wrap)
                           {
                             $earliest = $_.Substring($IndexIntoString, $wrap).LastIndexOf(' ')
                             $latest = $_.Substring($IndexIntoString + $wrap).IndexOf(' ')
                             $BreakPoint = &{
                                  if ($earliest -gt ($wrap + $latest)) { $earliest }
                                  else { $wrap + $latest }
                             }
                             if ($earliest -lt (($BreakPoint * 10)/100)) { $BreakPoint = $wrap } # in case it is a string without spaces
                             $padding + $_.Substring($IndexIntoString, $BreakPoint).Trim() + "`r`n"
                             $IndexIntoString += $BreakPoint
                           }
                           if ($IndexIntoString -lt $length) { $padding + $_.Substring($IndexIntoString).Trim() + "`r`n" }
                           else { "`r`n" }
                      }
                    }
                    else { "'$($string -replace '''', '''''')'" }
               }
               'Char'  { "([int]$inputObject)" }
               {
                    @('byte', 'decimal', 'double', 'float', 'single', 'int', 'int32', 'int16', `
                    'long', 'int64', 'sbyte', 'uint16', 'uint32', 'uint64') -contains $_
               }
               { "$inputObject" } # rendered as is without single quotes
               'PSNoteProperty' { "$(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $inputObject.Value -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" }
               'Array'   { "$($inputObject | ForEach { "`r`n$padding- $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })" }
               'HashTable'{
                    ("$($inputObject.GetEnumerator() | ForEach {
                      "`r`n$padding  $($_.Name): " +
                       (ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $_.Value -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))
                     })")
               }
               'PSObject' { ("$($inputObject.PSObject.Properties | ForEach { "`r`n$padding $($_.Name): " + (ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1)) })") }
               'generic'  { "$($inputObject.Keys | ForEach { "`r`n$padding  $($_):  $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $inputObject.$_ -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })" }
               'Object' { ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | Select-Object name | ForEach { "`r`n$padding $($_.name): $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $NestingLevel -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })") }
               'XML' { ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | where-object { @('xml', 'schema') -notcontains $_.name } | Select-Object name | ForEach { "`r`n$padding $($_.name): $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })") }
               'DataRow' { ("$($inputObject | Get-Member -membertype properties | Select-Object name | ForEach { "`r`n$padding $($_.name):  $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $inputObject.$($_.name) -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel + 1))" })") }
               #  'SqlDataReader'{$all = $inputObject.FieldCount; while ($inputObject.Read()) {for ($i = 0; $i -lt $all; $i++) {"`r`n$padding $($Reader.GetName($i)): $(ConvertTo-YAML -inputObject $($Reader.GetValue($i)) -depth $depth -NestingLevel ($NestingLevel+1))"}}
               default { "'$inputObject'" }
            }
          }
          catch
          {
            write-error "Error'$($_)' in script $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName) $($_.InvocationInfo.Line.Trim()) (line $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)) char $($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine) executing $($_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand) on $type object '$($inputObject)' Class: $($inputObject.GetType().Name) BaseClass: $($inputObject.GetType().BaseType.Name) "
          }
          finally { }
     }

     END { }
  }
  ```

**Note:** Try Convertto-json also apart from all these.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Wow, nice functions. Now I only need to know how to get the output into my Javascript;)

Comment: @30000MONKEYS : Happy to help ..Goodluck

Comment: @30000MONKEYS:  Accept the answer if it helps you .

Comment: [JSON Parsing docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)