# npm package.json OS specific script

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I would like to create a `package.json` build script that executes slightly different set of commands when run from Windows, Linux, Mac.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to put it in `package.json` file that will run without problems at every system.

Here is an example that I would like to have:

```
"scripts" : {
    "build.windows" : "echo do windows specific stuff",
    "build.linux" : "echo do linux specific stuff",
    "build.mac" : "echo do mac specific stuff",
    "build" : "??????????????" <- what to put here to execute script designed for OS
                                  on which npm is running
}
```

Comment: [`shx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx#install) (tiny) package is an easy way of running shell-specific commands without altering a script's name.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There's an NPM package called `run-script-os` ( [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os) | [GitHub](https://github.com/charlesguse/run-script-os) ) that doesn't require you to write any additional files, and this can be convenient if what you're trying to do is very simple. For example, in your `package.json`, you might have something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "run-script-os",
    "test:darwin:linux": "export NODE_ENV=test && mocha",
    "test:win32": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& mocha"
}
```

Then you could run `npm test` on Windows, Mac, or Linux and get similar (or different!) results on each.

Comment: What is the equivalent syntax to use "test:unit" with "run-script-os"?

Comment: @BerndPrager were you able to find the equivalent of above ?

Comment: I used "prettier-check": "run-script-os" and it worked!

Comment: Hey @BerndPrager, @PrabhatMishra

You would do 

`"test:unit": "run-script-os",`
`"test:unit:win32": "..."`

The idea is you have run-script-os called on the main thing you want (in this case test:unit) and then create the other versions with trailing operating systems (test:unit:win32, etc)

Comment: It should be **terminal**-based and not ***OS***-based

Comment: Also, this answer is not good when you need to write terminal-specific commands for a **specific** reserved-word script, for example the `prepare` stage, or `publish`

Comment: This could be the accepted answer. Thanks @Dave

Answer (score 40):

You can use scripts with **node run-script** command. `npm run` is a shortcut of it.

Package json:

```
"scripts" : {
    "build-windows" : "node build-windows.js",
    "build-linux" : "node build-linux.js",
    "build-mac" : "node build-mac.js",
    "build" : "node build.js"
}
```

Command line:

```
npm run build-windows
```

If you don't like it, you can use commands inside node.js.

Package json:

```
"scripts" : {
    "build" : "node build.js"
}
```

Build.js

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var os = require('os');

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }

// Run command depending on the OS
if (os.type() === 'Linux') 
   exec("node build-linux.js", puts); 
else if (os.type() === 'Darwin') 
   exec("node build-mac.js", puts); 
else if (os.type() === 'Windows_NT') 
   exec("node build-windows.js", puts);
else
   throw new Error("Unsupported OS found: " + os.type());
```

Comment: I think `exec("node build-windows.js", puts);` should be something dependent on `os`.

Comment: @gawi you are right. I wrote "control OS , then run command".

Comment: I would put in the answer then: `if (os.type() === 'Linux') exec("node build-linux.js", puts); else if (os.type() === 'Darwin') exec("node build-mac.js", puts); else if (os.type() === 'Windows_NT') exec("node build-windows.js", puts);`

Comment: You can use `process.env.OS` instead of requiring `os` modules. Just thought to mention.

Comment: @hurricane If i am executing a ps1 file by using exec('build-windows.ps1', puts), its not executing that file, rather just opening it. Any idea how that can be fixed

Comment: @whyAto8 I think you are missing your run command for PowerShell. Try to use `spawn` instead of exec. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js

Comment: @hurricane Well, i was able to run this , it seemed like a machine specific issue, as i tried on windows server and it worked. But, now the "node build.js" doesnt seem to run which is in package.json on the same windows server, do we need to add something for node to run on windows.

Comment: What I liked about using build-prefix solution is that it also runs postbuild-prefix accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely *not* the most reliable way to do this, but you can technically accomplish this all in one npm script:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "( Write-Output 'Powershell' && ./tools/build-ps.ps1 ) || 
                  ( CALL ./tools/build-cmd.bat ) || 
                  ( bash -c 'uname -a | grep -q -i Linux' && bash -c ./tools/build-linux.sh ) ||
                  ( bash -c 'uname -a | grep -q -i Darwin' && bash -c ./tools/build-mac.sh )"
        }
}
```

Comment: This is nice because it doesn't require running an extra Node process which takes 40ms minimum on M1 Mac.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do in the scripts, but it's likely that you can use **npm cli packages** to effectively add cross-platform commands to any shell.

For example, if you wanted to *delete a directory*, you could use separate syntaxes for windows and linux:

```bash
rm -rf _site     # bash
rd /s /q _site   # cmd
```

Or instead, you could use the npm package [**`rimraf`**](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf#cli) which works cross platform:

```
npx rimraf _site
```

To take Dave P's example above, you could set environment variables with [**`cross-env`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "npx cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha",
}
```

And if you don't want to use [**`npx`**](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) to install scripts live, you can install them globally ahead of time like this:

```bash
npm i cross-env -g
```

Here's a post I wrote on [making NPM scripts work cross platform](https://web.archive.org/web/20220722094802/https://docgov.dev/posts/npm-scripts/) which explores some of these options