# Applying different package.json to different OS ( window , mac)

Tags: node.js

I use `dotenv` module to apply .env in my projects.

In windows, prefix `cross-env` should be put before every setting environment scripts in package.json.

For example, this is my `yarn build` command in windows.

```
scripts: {
...
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn build:client && cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn build:server",
...
}
```

I use both window and mac OS in different device,
don't want to remove / put cross-env prefix each times I change my device.

Is there ways to automative scripts I can make to edit `scripts` section in package.json?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082648/npm-package-json-os-specific-script

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ yeap. as bravemaster mentioned same contents earlier, it helped me alot. thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1):

I found the simplest way to use npm module named `run-script-os` [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)

Thank you for all the comments here.