# What shell-like syntax is supported by node in package.json scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

In my Node `package.json` scripts, I can use some light shell syntax:

```
scripts: {
  detect-cheese: "echo 'Is there cheese?' $($* | grep -q cheese && echo yep || echo nope)"
}
```

```
$ yarn run detect-cheese apple cheese banana
Is there cheese? yep
```

But this seems to be a subset of Bash (or some other shell's) syntax. For instance, optional arguments are hard to do:

```
scripts: {
  fox: "echo fox $1", 
  cat: "echo cat ${1-Rufus}"
}

$ yarn run fox
Unbound argument #1
$ yarn run cat Chester
Unbound variable "1-Rufus"
```

Are the details of this shell-like syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: it depends on your platform - apparently there's a package that can make sense of it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197655/23528

Comment: documentation link: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#exiting

Answer (score 2):

### npm and yarn v1

The shell on unix like systems is `sh` so stick to [POSIX sh definitions](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html).

A default for a null or undefined value in `sh` is `${VAR:-default}`

```
cat: "echo \"cat ${1:-Rufus}\""
```

### yarn 2+ berry

Use a minimal `sh` implementation [`yarnpkg-shell`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/tree/master/packages/yarnpkg-shell) which supports the basic shell syntax but is not fully POSIX compliant. This enables all environments, with or without `sh`, to execute `package.json` scripts in the same manner.

---

Test running the following:

```
printf 'VAR=  %s\n' "$VAR"
printf 'VAR-  %s\n' "${VAR-def}"
printf 'VAR:- %s\n' "${VAR:-def}"
printf 'VAR+  %s\n' "${VAR+def}"
printf 'VAR:+ %s\n' "${VAR:+def}"
```

via:

```
{
  "name": "so36729207-npm-sh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "sh": "printf 'VAR=  %s\n' \"$VAR\"; printf 'VAR-  %s\n' \"${VAR-def}\"; printf 'VAR:- %s\n' \"${VAR:-def}\"; printf 'VAR+  %s\n' \"${VAR+def}\"; printf 'VAR:+ %s\n' \"${VAR:+def}\""
  }
}
```

Produces the same results for `sh` in dash/Debian, ash/Alpine and zsh/macos environment

```
$ docker run --rm so36729207/alpine npm run sh      

> so36729207-npm-sh@1.0.0 sh
> printf 'VAR=  %s
> ' "$VAR"; printf 'VAR-  %s
> ' "${VAR-def}"; printf 'VAR:- %s
> ' "${VAR:-def}"; printf 'VAR+  %s
> ' "${VAR+def}"; printf 'VAR:+ %s
> ' "${VAR:+def}"

VAR=  
VAR-  def
VAR:- def
VAR+  
VAR:+
```

```
$ docker run --rm --env VAR= so36729207/alpine npm run sh

> so36729207-npm-sh@1.0.0 sh
> printf 'VAR=  %s
> ' "$VAR"; printf 'VAR-  %s
> ' "${VAR-def}"; printf 'VAR:- %s
> ' "${VAR:-def}"; printf 'VAR+  %s
> ' "${VAR+def}"; printf 'VAR:+ %s
> ' "${VAR:+def}"

VAR=  
VAR-  
VAR:- def
VAR+  def
VAR:+
```

```
$ docker run --rm --env VAR=a so36729207/alpine npm run sh

> so36729207-npm-sh@1.0.0 sh
> printf 'VAR=  %s
> ' "$VAR"; printf 'VAR-  %s
> ' "${VAR-def}"; printf 'VAR:- %s
> ' "${VAR:-def}"; printf 'VAR+  %s
> ' "${VAR+def}"; printf 'VAR:+ %s
> ' "${VAR:+def}"

VAR=  a
VAR-  a
VAR:- a
VAR+  def
VAR:+ def
```

Comment: but not on windows!

Comment: Well yes, but I'm assuming OP is sane =)

Comment: Ah, cool. Actually both `${VAR:-default}` and `${VAR-default}` work in `bash` and `sh` but do slightly different things (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It looks like the `:` is required in the `node` version. But it also appears to me that `node` does the same thing for `${1:-foo}` and `${1:+foo}`, which is inconsistent with `bash` and `sh`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @Matt ideally we shouldn't answer just to the OPs question - people in the future will come here wanting to know what it is more generally.

Comment: @Sasgorilla oh right, null instead of undefined, I'll do some checking

Comment: @Sasgorilla what os/distro are you running on? it might be the flavour of `sh` that presents.