# Make package.json scripts work on both macOS and Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, jasmine, package.json

I am using Jasmine test suite to run tests in my codebase.

It works great on my Mac. the command is

`open SpecRunner.html`

Here's the full scripts object:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm install",
    "test:local": "open SpecRunner.html",
    "test:remote": "karma start"
  },
```

The problem I am having is that my friend told me `npm run test:local` isn't working on his Windows machine. I believe the correct command in `start SpecRunner.html`.

What's the best way to make this compatible across operating systems?

ChatGPT recommended this solution:

```
"scripts": {
  "open-spec": "cross-env OS_TYPE=$(uname) npm run open-spec-$(uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')",
  "open-spec-darwin": "open SpecRunner.html",
  "open-spec-linux": "xdg-open SpecRunner.html",
  "open-spec-win32": "start SpecRunner.html"
}
```

I'd prefer a simple way to combine the command into one script though. Is that possible? I don't have a Windows machine to test myself! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm package.json OS specific script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082648/npm-package-json-os-specific-script)

Comment: Can't you use the npm package [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) for this? i.e. `npm i -D open-cli` and then use `"open-cli SpecRunner.html"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already being answered here before. Take a look at this question here: [npm package.json OS specific script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082648/npm-package-json-os-specific-script).

I believe the second answer is what you want. Wrapping it with some node if else. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082999/10880357.

But I like the first one better (which is similar as GPT), looks like you and your friend are starting a project or something. It will not hurt to type
:
test:mac
or
test:windows

My advice for you: Keep focused on what is going to bring your value.

Answer (score 1):

The npm package [`open:10.0.4`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) provides a cross-platform solution to this.

First, install the package:

```bash
npm i -D open-cli
```

Then update your script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:local": "open-cli SpecRunner.html",
  }
}
```