# How to call a Powershell script in my vs code extension

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my vscode extension I would like to call an external powershell script and pass a parameter to that script. How to accomplish this in typescript?

So the process is as follows...

The user activates the command palette, enter the keyword for the extension I'm conding, and inputs a parameter in the command palette. This activates a powershell script that takes the input from the user as a parameter and then do stuff.

Could the powershell script be included in the extension or will it have to be external?

Answer (score 2):

Look here: [Execute Powershell script from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js)

And `showQuickPick` here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window