# Call local PowerShell Script from Browser/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, powershell

I know this is security-wise an absolute No-Go. But I have a customer, who has an angular application running internally only. This means the workers of the customer don't have internet access in the browser in which they use the application, and it is running in a virtual machine.

So they don't really care about browser-security, since they only use the application on it.

Now they have following use case:

1. User clicks a button in the Angular app
2. A powershell script on the local machine gets executed

So my question is, is there a way to call a local Powershell script with using Angular/Javascript?

---

**My current idea**

I could start a local NodeJS server on the virtual machines (always when they are booting) running on localhost:8080 for example, which listens for Rest calls.

When the user hits the button, the Angular app will make a Rest-Call to localhost:8080, which is the client node-server and the node-server executes the Powershell-script.

I see that's possible with: [Execute Powershell script from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js/10181488)

---

So does this make sense?
Or is there a better way to accomplish something like this? (As I said if there's a possibility to turn off browser security it's ok.)

Answer (score 1):

Other way to achieve this is by registering a custom protocol with your application. That is how lot of apps like slack, skype etc work. But, your initial solution seems more platform independent.

Comment: Well it will be Windows only, so it wouldn't matter. Can you elaborate what you mean with custom protocol?

Comment: I haven't done this myself in the past. Please check this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) for more info