# Execute Powershell script from Node.js with ES6 Modules enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I need to execute a Powershell file on my NodeJS server and the answer to that is [allready given in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js).

However I am unable to replace `const { exec } = require('child_process');` or `var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;` with the needed Import since my Server is running with ES6 Modules enabled in the package.json `"type": "module"`

Does anybody know how to properly import the needed Module in this specific case? Here is the code I was trying out on my server which are from the Users **Honest Objections** and **muffel** posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js):

[**Honest Objections**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3816379/honest-objections) **Code:**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('command here', {'shell':'powershell.exe'}, (error, stdout, stderr)=> {
    // do whatever with stdout
})
```

[**muffel**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793961/muffel) **Code:**

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
child = spawn("powershell.exe",["c:\\temp\\helloworld.ps1"]);
child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});
child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});
child.on("exit",function(){
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});
child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

Comment: I am getting following Error: `require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'path\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.` And I thought it is either ES module scope or CommonJS. I will make sure to do more research on ES module scope / CommonJS

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: In this case I am using `node ps.js` in my Terminal

Comment: Does it work after you replace CommonJS imports with ES6 imports?

Comment: After replacing my CommonJS imports with ES6 imports Everything works as expeccted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace CommonJS imports

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
```

with ES6 imports

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
```

at module scope and with

```
const { exec } = import('child_process');
var spawn = import('child_process').spawn;
```

at function scope.

Comment: But how would I translate `var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;` in ES6  imports? After importing my modules the way you taught I would still need to define `child` to use it  (muffel Code example)

Comment: @Baul I don't understand your question. `spawn` is the same object in both codes. `var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;` is just a short form of `var spawn = require("child_process").spawn; var child;`. `child` is uninitialized after that line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unaware that you could initialize variables this way. I feel kinda dumb for wasting your time like this. But nether the less, thank you for teaching me and solving my problem.