# Execute PowerShell script from NodeJS results in "running scripts is disabled on this system"

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line-interface, executionpolicy

I'm attempting to run a powershell script from node. Here is my current code:

```
try {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
    child = spawn("powershell.exe", ['-file', "..\\build.ps1", "-devmode"])
    child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
        //console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
    });
    child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
        console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    });
    child.on("exit",function(){
        console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    });
    child.stdin.end(); //end input
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

The code is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js).  When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Powershell Errors: File C:\<path>\build.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information,
see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I have tried setting the execution policy `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope LocalMachine` and I also tried just bypassing it when calling the script, like this:

```
child = spawn("powershell.exe", ['-ExecutionPolicy ByPass', '-file', "..\\build.ps1", "-devmode"])
```

This just resulted in `The term '-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

So how can I execute this script from node without execution policy errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the Windows **PowerShell CLI** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) with the **`-File` parameter to directly invoke a `.ps1` *script file***,  using the **`-ExecutionPolicy` CLI parameter** is indeed **the only effective way to override the script-file [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) in effect** *ad hoc*, for the given process only: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is equivalent to calling 
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force` from inside a PowerShell session.

However, to do so from a `spawn` call, **each argument - irrespective of whether it represent a parameter *name* or *value* - must be passed *as its own array element***:

```
spawn("powershell.exe", ['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-file', "..\\build.ps1", "-devmode"])
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

In your attempt, `spawn` of necessity encloses `'-ExecutionPolicy Bypass'` in `"..."` on the resulting command line (on Windows), given that it contains spaces.

When `powershell.exe` parses the resulting command line, it does *not* recognize 
`"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass"` as an attempt to pass the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter with a value; in fact, it doesn't recognize this argument as a CLI parameter at all, and therefore defaults to treating it as *PowerShell source code* - i.e. as if it had been passed to the *default* CLI parameter, `-Command` (`-c`).

That is, in effect your attempt was tantamount to submitting `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass ...` as a command from inside a PowerShell session, which results in the error you saw.

Answer (score -1):

```
spawn("Powershell.exe",['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', "file/path/tmp1/test.ps1"]);
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to help future readers why this answer could solve the issue. Thank you.