# How to create and run a stateless command in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, io, filesystems, decorator, wrapper

A stateless file system commands allows you to mutate the file system even when a command is run
in the current directory.

One advantage is that is does not corrupt the system as the scripts are abstracted away.
One implementation is  the use of decorator.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Define the wrapper function
function wrapCommand(command, directoryState) {
  return function(args) {
    // Merge the current directory state with any new state passed in
    const newState = Object.assign({}, directoryState, args.state);

    // Create a new object to use as the WeakMap key
    const keyObject = { cwd: process.cwd() };

    // Create a new WeakMap to store the directory state for this command
    const stateMap = new WeakMap();
    stateMap.set(keyObject, newState);

    // Spawn the child process with the new directory state
    const childProcess = spawn(command, args.args, {
      stdio: 'pipe',
      env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { directoryState: stateMap }),
      cwd: process.cwd()
    });

    // Listen for the child process to exit and update the directory state
    childProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      directoryState = stateMap.get(keyObject);
    });

    // Log the output of the child process to the console
    childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  };
}

// Define the initial directory state
let directoryState = {};

// Wrap the 'ls' command
const ls = wrapCommand('ls', directoryState);

// Call the 'ls' command with some initial state
ls({ state: { foo: 'bar' } })

// Call the 'ls' command with some additional state
ls({ state: { baz: 'qux' } });
```

The following documented code wraps a command,but throws an internal error:

```bash
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ls ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ls',
  path: 'ls',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Since this is an internal error,and not knowing how to debug using **node --inspect ** ,i have decieded to post it here.

I am new to debug my code.

Comment: `ls` is a Linux command, are you running this on windows?

Comment: Yes,it is a linux command,but I am using windows Powershell 7 which has ls as an alias

Comment: Well the error is telling you `Error: spawn ls ENOENT`. The ls command is not found.  You might need to set the `shell` option on the `spawn` to use powershell.  Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js

Comment: I have tried the code on wsl(Windows Subsystem for linux) It works like a charm.The problem now is to get it working on windows powershell.I will rewrite it to work on powershell as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation that is both compatable on windows ,and linux systems.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

function wrapCommand(command, directoryState, debug) {
    return function (args) {
        const newState = Object.assign({}, directoryState, args.state);
        const keyObject = { cwd: process.cwd() };
        const stateMap = new WeakMap();
        stateMap.set(keyObject, newState);

        let childProcess;
        if (process.platform === 'win32') {
            // On Windows, use "powershell.exe" instead of a command
            childProcess = spawn('powershell.exe', ['-Command', command, ...args.args], {
                stdio: 'pipe',
                env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { directoryState: stateMap }),
                cwd: process.cwd()
            });
        } else {
            // On Linux and other platforms, spawn a shell with the command
            childProcess = spawn('sh', ['-c', `${command} ${args.args.join(' ')}`], {
                stdio: 'pipe',
                env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { directoryState: stateMap }),
                cwd: process.cwd()
            });
        }

        childProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
            directoryState = stateMap.get(keyObject);
        });
        if (debug) {
            const changes = [];
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(args.state)) {
                const oldValue = directoryState[key];
                changes.push(`${key}: ${oldValue} -> ${value}`);
            }
            console.log(`Changes to directory state: ${changes.join(', ')}`);

            childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
        }

    };
}

let directoryState = {};

const ls = wrapCommand('ls', directoryState); // Use'ls' on Linux and 'Get-ChildItem' on Windows

// Call the 'ls' command with some initial state
ls({ args: ['-al'], state: { foo: 'bar' } })
// Call the 'ls' command with some additional state
ls({ args: ['-l'], state: { baz: 'qux' } });

const gci = wrapCommand('gci', directoryState);
gci({ args: [], state: { foo: 'baz' } });
```